# Как сверстать такие элементы?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Использую bootstrap-4

[image: скрин]

На данный момент, сверстал так:
Задние пунктирные линии это одно изображение, поставил как background.
Каждый блок (иконка и текст) позиционирую через absolute.
При моей ширине экрана (1920) выглядит нормально, но если уменьшить или увеличить экран, то все ужасно сползает..

Comment: Ну как бы раз Вы сверстали с позиционированием, то при адаптации до HD (а то и меньше) придется также и перепозиционировать под каждый размер

Comment: А какие еще есть способы верстки для таких элементов?

Comment: (кажется у меня дежа вю...) вообще оторвите руки дизайнеру для начала)) А если серьезно, то попробуйте сверстать на флексах или таблицах, просто смещая контент внутри маргином, линию, естественно, бэкграундом. Верстка на позиционировании это самый крайний и нежелательный вариант.

Comment: Дизайнеры — вообще страшные люди) Попробуй просто сделать это всё одной картинкой и не мучиться с позиционированием)

Comment: Если нужна не адаптивная верстка, то в общем это не проблема, можете сделать по этому [принципу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704408/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), либо при адаптиве на медиа запросах просто поставить их друг за другом

Comment: По сути 2 варианта - либо абсолютное позиционирование, либо svg

Comment: И если у вас уже что-то сверстано, и вы ждете какой-то конкретной подсказки - то добавляйте код.