# CSS, интерактивная карта, соединить углы зоны

Tags: html, css, карты

Имеется интерактивная карта 1000px на 1000px.
Имеется база данных в которой постоянно обновляются эти зоны в виде их крайних 4 точек и передаются в пикселях.
Пример зоны:

```
Первая точка top:100px; left:100px;
Вторая точка top:-100px; left:-100px;
Третья точка top:200px; left:200px;
Четвертая точка top:-200px; left:-200px;
```

Получаем что-то вроде такого (извините что криво):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно сам вопрос - как можно соединить в квадрат с заливкой эти точки? (через CSS, HTML)

Значения для точки 1 top и left задаются через тег `{zone1_top} {zone1_left}`
Для второй {zone2_top} {zone2_left} и так далее

Вот пример как выводится одна точка зоны (один ее край):

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:{zone1_top}px; left:{zone1_left}; background-color: red; width:16px; height:16px;"></div>
```

Как это будет выглядеть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Жду помощи!

Comment: пожалуй только свг, если выделенная область всегда квадрат, то можно и css

Comment: @kizoso, у тя был подобный вопрос?

Comment: @Air, да но это наверное не совсем то - [Как сделать соединительную линию под наклоном между двумя точками?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/704408/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8), если нужен квадрат например, а если нет то вариантов не много

Comment: @kizoso, ты свой вопрос решила?

Comment: @Air, на широких - как в примере, на адаптив разбила на блоки получилось просто по порядку определения, хотелось простого css решения, это оказалось самым простым

Comment: Есть какие-то решения касательно моего вопроса? Нужно конкретно реализовать квадратные зоны на интерактивной карте при помощи 4 точек

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если у вас происходит вставка координат из базы прямо в HTML, то, думаю, вам подойдет решение на SVG:

```html
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <path d="M 20,20 L80,20 L80,80 L20,80 z" fill="#000" />
</svg>
```

В вашем случае это будет так:

```
<svg width="200" height="200">
  <path d="M {zone1_left},{zone1_top} L{zone2_left},{zone2_top} L{zone3_left},{zone3_top} L{zone4_left},{zone4_top} z" fill="#000" />
</svg>
```

Comment: благодарю, отличное решение

Comment: Не стесняйтесь отметить ответ принятым )